# <span> not starting where it starts where I want it to on new line

Tags: html, css

In the image you can see that if the title of the sidebar link is too long it goes to the next line. However it starts where the icon is located and not where the start of the span is. How would I style the class "side-nav-item" to where it will format where Administrator when it is shifted to the new line it starts where Give is.

```html
<li class="side-nav-item">
  <a data-bs-toggle="collapse" href="#userAccess" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="userAccess"
      class="side-nav-link">
      <i class="uil-layer-group"></i>
      <span>User Access</span>
      <span class="menu-arrow"></span>
  </a>
  <div class="collapse" id="userAccess" data-bs-parent="#accordion">
      <ul>
          <li class="side-nav-item">
              <a href="/task/add-location-access" class="side-nav-link">
                  <i class="uil-shield-check"></i>
                  <span> Give user access - Administrator</span>
              </a>
          </li>
          <li class="side-nav-item">
              <a href="/task/remove-location-access" class="side-nav-link">
                  <i class="uil-shield-slash"></i>
                  <span> Remove</span>
              </a>
          </li>
      </ul>
  </div>
</li>
```

[image]

Comment: Please include your CSS so we can see how it's currently being styled.

Answer (score 1):

Style `<span>` inside `<a></a>` as an inline-block. The behaviour you are seeing is expected from inline elements like `<span>` and `<i>`. Checkout concepts of inline elements, block elements and 'display' property in CSS. I am assuming you are new to HTML and CSS, so I suggest you begin with a good hands on video tutorial.

Answer (score -1):

try this ,

```
<span
  style="width:400px;text-align:start;height:max-content;"
> 
   Give user access - Administrator
</span>
```